# How to update external files used by an app?

Tags: android

I developing a kind of user manual app for android. I have large and in future increasing number video and pdf files located In folders located in external storage from which the app reads the files.

What methods could be used to deliver the files for the apps user and how could those files be easily kept up to date. This feature does not have to be part of the app itself so it could be a other app etc. The app is delivered for relatively small number of users using download link etc.

Reason for having the files locally on the device is that they should be able to be accessed offline.

Comment: I think it's better to save the files in the cloud. That way the user will download only the file he needs and you can update them easily. And after each update the user will get a notification to download the new version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to versionize files in the cloud. 
Just use an integer, after file is updated, it increments the counter.

Once you are online, you check local versions vs cloud versions, if cloud versions have higher counter, you update the file.